# Renaming text file names in bulk

Tags: python

I have bulk text files in gdrive.

```
folder1/folder2/0001193125-13-085083.txt
folder1/folder2/0001193125-12-086217.txt
...
```

I want to change the name of the text files as 1, 2, 3, 4...

I tried below code:

```
import os
path= "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/10/APA"

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join([str(index), '.txt'])))
```

I got below error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-51-6712110edbbb> in <module>()
      6 import os
      7 
----> 8 for index, file in enumerate(files):
      9     os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join([str(index), '.jpg'])))

TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you show us where you declared the `files` variable?

Comment: `files` is not defined. You need to [edit] the question to include a [mre]. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want more advice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious comments and help, the below message fixed it :) have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
path= "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/10/APA"
abs_path = os.path.abspath(path)

if not os.path.isdir(abs_path):
  print("No such directory")
  exit()

files = os.listdir(abs_path)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
  abs_path_file = os.path.join(abs_path, file)
  abs_path_file_new = os.path.join(abs_path, "{}.txt".format(index))
  os.rename(abs_path_file, abs_path_file_new)
```

To apply it to all subfolders (I would test this on a small folder first):

```
import os
root= "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/10"
abs_path_root = os.path.abspath(root)

if not os.path.isdir(root):
  print("No such root directory")
  exit()

folders_to_visit = [root]

while len(folders_to_visit) > 0:
  abs_path_folder = folders_to_visit.pop()
  files = os.listdir(abs_path_folder)

  index = 1
  for file in files:
    abs_path_file = os.path.join(abs_path_folder, file)

    if os.path.isdir(abs_path_file):
      folders_to_visit.append(abs_path_file)
      continue

    abs_path_file_new = os.path.join(abs_path_folder, "{}.txt".format(index))
    os.rename(abs_path_file, abs_path_file_new)
    index +=1
```

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING. IT WORKED. thank you so much :) have an amazing day.

Comment: I have another question, If I need to apply this name-change to all folders, path= "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/10/APA"  what would you suggest for loop? like: in addition to folder APA, other folders located in folder 10

Comment: As in `10/APA` has subfolders and you want to run this script on all the subfolders (and the subfolders within that)? Do you want the file numbers to reset for each subfolder?

Comment: Exactly...  for all subfolders located at folder 10.

Comment: Edited my comment to add code for that! Please see this link on how to accept answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to define files variable in your code which you seemed to miss. Secondly, you need to filter out files so that you only have text files to avoid renaming all files. You can acheive this as follows:

```
import os
path= "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/10/APA/"
text_files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith('.txt)]

 for index, file in enumerate(text_files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path, ''.join([str(index), '.txt'])))
```